# In R, why does subtracting numerics from NA return NA but subtracting dates from NA return an error?

Tags: r

In R, if you subtract a numeric from NA it will return NA:

```
> x <- 1
> NA - x
[1] NA
```

But if you try to subtract a date from NA it returns an error:

```
> x <- as.Date("2014-04-22")
> NA - x
Error in `-.Date`(NA, x) : can only subtract from "Date" objects
```

I am interested in why R returns an error. As I understand it, "Date" objects are just a heyrepresentation of the integer difference from the origin (defaulting to 1970-01-01).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
> as.Date(NA)-as.Date("2014-04-22")
Time difference of NA days
```

You may, however, subtract an integer from a date:

```
> as.Date("2014-04-22")-NA
[1] NA
> as.Date("2014-04-22")-2
[1] "2014-04-20"
```

The reason for this is that the `-` operator is in fact an S3 method -- ``overloading'' (invoked method selection) is done according to the type of its first argument. Try:

```
> get("-.Date")
```

If this was an S4 method, it could have been overloaded to take the type of the second argument into account.

For more details on S3 method dispatch mechanism, see [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/UseMethod.html).

Comment: Well. that is interesting. I fixed it by converting the dates to numerics differencing and the back to dates. Do you know why `NA` needs to be converted to a "Date" object?

Comment: look at ?Ops.Date. For Operators to work, objects need to be of "Date" class

Comment: More precisely, the first argument should be of `Date` class.

Comment: I understand that objects need to be of the same class, but I never realized that NA needed to be converted. Thanks.

Comment: `typeof(NA) == "logical"`